# 404 error when trying to load ADAL.js ins Angular2

Tags: angular, adal.js

Anyone have any ideas why I would get a 404 when trying to execute: import 'expose?AuthenticationContext!../../../node_modules/adal-angular/lib/adal.js';

The path is correct and the adal.js file is definitely there (if I paste in the URL into another tab in the browser it opens). I loaded "expose" (with a lot of warning messages).  Here is the full error

Error loading http://localhost:56580/expose?AuthenticationContext!http://localhost:56580/node_modules/adal-angular/lib/adal.js as "expose?AuthenticationContext!../../../node_modules/adal-angular/lib/adal.js" from http://localhost:56580/app/components/domain/auth.provider.js

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

`const AuthenticationContext = require('../../../node_modules/adal-angular/lib/adal.js');`